# How can I Mock CompletableFuture in Java

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mocking

The calls in API:

```
        CompletableFuture<Beneficiary> beneficiaryCompletableFuture =
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
                    beneficiaryService.validateAndGetCustomer(dto.getBeneficiary()), forkJoinPool);


    CompletableFuture<List<Product>> productsCompletableFuture =
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
                    productService.validateAndGetProducts(dto.getProductCodeList()), forkJoinPool);
```

When forkJoinPool is a Spring Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ForkJoinConfig {

    @Bean
    public ForkJoinPool getForkJoinPool(){
        return new ForkJoinPool();
    }
}
```

When i try to test this in Junit the call is stucked, the test does not work...

[image: stucked_test]

I really don't know can i simple Mock a CompletableFuture.supplyAsync and identify what is Product or what is Beneficiary...

Comment: Don't.  Use a real one.  There's no reason to mock a Future of any kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a component with has the same method of original static class, so when you need to mock, you can use @Mock.

```
@Component
public class ApplicationCompletableFuture {
    public <U> CompletableFuture<U> supplyAsync(Supplier<U> supplier,
                                                ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier, forkJoinPool);
    }
}
```

```
CompletableFuture<Pet> branchCompletableFuture =
        applicationCompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> petService.validatePet(dto.getPetCode), forkJoinPool);
```

```
when(applicationCompletableFuture.supplyAsync(any(),any()))
        .thenReturn(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(pet));
```